# How to change HighCharts theme using Python ezhc?

Tags: python, themes

I have been using `ezhc` package, it is a very useful tool to manipulate highcharts object using Python.
But I have desperately tried to change the themes of the Highcharts graph I am producing, based on the demo notebook found on Github [link](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/oscar6echo/ezhc/blob/master/demo_ezhc_themes_and_global_options.ipynb)

Anything I have tried is unsuccessful, it seems that this part of the code, which should override  `globaloptions` of all the charts, does not work as expected:

```
hc_global = hc.GlobalOptions(th.themes['dark-unica'])
hc_global.inject(verbose=True)
```

I see the js `hc_global.js` seems to be correctly created, but does not override the `globalOptions` of the chart. The visual of the chart output after is unchanged, no matter what theme is chosen

Am I doing something wrong? Does anybody successfully ran the example notebook and observed the theme change?

Thanks a lot for your help